# PHP @mail textarea $message not being sent

Tags: php, email

So this must look as another PHP email question. However, after researching and trying all available replies on Stackoverflow, I can't seem to get the `<textarea name="description"></textarea>` to get the content and send it with the rest of the email $to, $from, $body and $headers:

Here's the HTML:

```
<form method="post" id="tarqus_form">
  <div class="inner-frame inverse p-7">
    <h5>Hola,</h5>
    <div>
      <h5>mi nombre es</h5>
      <input type="text" class="name" name="name" placeholder="Nombre (obligatorio)" id="name">
    </div>
    <div>
      <h5>y me gustaría saber</h5>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h5>sobre:</h5>
      <input type="text" class="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Asunto" id="asunto">
    </div>
    <div>
      <h5>Me pueden responder</h5>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h5>a este:</h5>
      <input type="text" class="email" name="email" placeholder="Correo electrónico (obligatorio)" id="email">
    </div>
    <div>
      <h5>Quisiera decir:</h5>
    </div>
    <div>


     <!-- HERE's the textarea -->
      <textarea name="description" rows="3" class="message" placeholder="Ingresa tu mensaje (obligatorio)" id="message"></textarea>
    </div>


    <div class="row pt-21">
      <div class="col-md-6 p-0">
        <h5>Antispam:</h5>
        <div>
          <h5>¿12-7+2?</h5>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="text" class="antispam pl-0 mt-7 ml-0" name="antispam" placeholder="Respuesta (obligatorio)" id="antispam">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="submit uppercase">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I'm creating some validations with jQuery and if they pass, the POST method is called. This hasn't been a problem because the email is actually being sent with everything I need except the message on the textarea. 
jQuery validations:

```
$("#tarqus_form").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var subject = $("#asunto").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var text = $("#message").val();
        var antispam = $("#antispam").val();
        var dataString = 'email=' + email + '&text=' + text + '&subject=' + subject + '&name=' + name;

        // Custom RegExp for verifying email authenticity
        function isValidEmail(emailAddress) {
          var pattern = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-   \uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);
          return pattern.test(emailAddress);
        };

        if (isValidEmail(email) && (name.length > 1) && (text.length > 1) && (antispam == 7)){
          $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "/form.php",
          data: dataString,
          success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
            $('#tarqus_form').fadeOut(500);
            $('.success').removeClass('hidden').fadeIn(500);
          }
          });
        } else{
          $('.error').removeClass('hidden').fadeIn(1000);
          setTimeout(function(){
            $('.error').addClass('hidden');
          }, 5000);
        }

        return false;
      });
```

When this passes, the form sends the email according to this PHP code:

```
<?php
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $subject = $_POST['subject'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $message = $_POST['description'];
            $from = 'TARQUS | Arquitectura MX <contacto@tarqus.mx>';
            $headers.="From:".$from."\n";


            $to = 'contacto@tarqus.mx';

            $body = "Nombre: $name\n Asunto: $subject\n E-Mail: $email\n Mensaje: $message\n";

            // detect & prevent header injections
            $test = "/(content-type|bcc:|cc:|to:)/i";
            foreach ( $_POST as $key => $val ) {
              if ( preg_match( $test, $val ) ) {
                exit;
              }
            }       

            @mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
        ?>
```

As you can see, I'm using the `$_POST` method for my `name="description"` textarea. I've also tried with the `$_REQUEST` method.

Here's an example email, all of the changes that I've made to the PHP code sent the email except for the $message in the $body:

```
Nombre: Name Lastname
Asunto: Subject
E-Mail: example@mail.com
Mensaje: === empty === :(
```

Comment: Check your data string var again... You send $_POST['text'] to php...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you got error on your php file

when you getting post DATA in ajax you sending TEXT not DESCRIPTION

```
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $subject = $_POST['subject'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $message = $_POST['text'];
        $from = 'TARQUS | Arquitectura MX <contacto@tarqus.mx>';
        $headers.="From:".$from."\n";
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I never thought about the datastring because everything I read about PHP is that it takes de name attribute of the textarea and inputs...